# phpDocumentor page-level docstrings

Tags: phpdoc

We have a page-level docblock like the following:

```
/**
* Functions for the processing, displaying, and searching of listings
*
* @package ListingFunctions
*
*/
```

The rest of the file has functions with their own docblocks.  But my team and I can't find this comment anywhere in the generated HTML output.  Is there some configuration or command-line stuff we need to turn on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using phpDocumentor 1.x, that "short description" piece should be the main description heading on the webpage for that given file.  It won't appear on those functions in that file... just on the file itself.  This is core behavior, that cannot be modified by runtime settings.