# phpDocumentor 2.0 Page-level DocBlock - Where is it?

Tags: phpdoc

I have a set of classes, each class is in its own file. I've added appropriate DocBlocks so that I get no errors or warnings when I build the documentation. Here is a very simplified example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Page level description.
 */

/**
 * Short class description.
 *
 * Longer description on what this class is all about.
 */
class Test {
    // a bunch of code
}
?>
```

When I run phpdoc on this class, the Page-level DocBlock does not appear anywhere in the generated HTML.

The reason for this is perhaps because version 2.0 is still in Alpha. Can someone enlighten me as to what I'm missing, if in fact I'm missing something?

Btw, I did do my homework on trying to find the answer. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411636/phpdocumentor-page-level-docstrings) from 2 months ago but it references an earlier version of phpDocumentor, and it doesn't look like the OP specified whether or not it answered the question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] a Page-level DocBlock is the first DocBlock in a file if it contains a @package tag. [...]

```
<?php
/**
 * Page-level DocBlock
 * @package pagepackage
 */
/**
 * Define DocBlock
 */
define("ahhhh","Now the Page-level DocBlock is for the page, and the Define DocBlock for the define");
?>
```

Reference:
http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_elements.pkg.html

Comment: I have the same issue. If I add the @package tag, the class, functions etc. for that page will appear in the documentation - but not the contents of the page-level DocBlock.