# Creating a description using phpdocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc

I can't figure out how to make a description for my script. On the official website and in the tutorials, they write blocks like this:

```
/**
 * This is the summary for a DocBlock.
 *
 * This is the description for a DocBlock. This text may contain
 * multiple lines and even some _markdown_.
 */
```

I use it for my script:

```
<?php

/**
 * Small Descripton.
 *
 * Large description to my script
 */

require_once("path2file.php");

echo "start report\n";

function myFunc() {
    // ...
}
```

This does not work

`phpDocumentor -f doc_b_test2.php  -t doc2`

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QawEB.png)

No description at this picture.
I managed to create a description for a function or class, but I want to get a description for the script. What am I doing wrong? Maybe this is impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpDocumentor 2.0 Page-level DocBlock - Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552777/phpdocumentor-2-0-page-level-docblock-where-is-it)

Comment: thanx, but its does not work. No packages in doc, no descriptions, no errors... I copied what was on the link, went to the original source, tried all the examples. Does not work

Comment: What version of phpDocumentor are you using ?

Comment: phpDocumentor v3.0.0